# Change the image of an image shape

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to be able to change the image of an image shape by clicking on an button in my userform.

In the internet I found the function `UserPicture`, but the image simply stays the same.

```
Private Sub ChangeImage_Click()
    ActivePresentation.Slides("Slide1").Shapes("SolutionA_Image").Visible = True

    ActivePresentation.Slides("Slide1").Shapes("SolutionA_Image").Fill.UserPicture ("D:\User\Desktop\SolutionWrong.jpg")
End Sub

Private Sub HideImage_Click()
    ActivePresentation.Slides("Slide1").Shapes("SolutionA_Image").Visible = False
End Sub
```

When I click on the `HideImage` button, the shape becomes invisible, so my selection of the shape appears to be right.

I also tried

```
ActivePresentation.Slides("Slide1").Shapes("SolutionA_Image").Fill.UserPicture "D:\User\SolutionWrong.jpg"
```

but this does not work either

**Edit**
Of course I checked the path to the new image, it's correct.

Comment: I just tested it and it works... What kind of shape is it?

Comment: I created it by selecting `picture` from the `insert` menu

Comment: Ah No wonder :) Do this. Insert~~>A rectangle Shape with no borders and now try it :)

Comment: It works! Thank you very much! Would you like to post this as an answer? Then I could accept it.

Comment: That's ok :) You can answer your own question and accept it (it is even highly recommended) See this... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking ;)

Comment: I know, but I thought you would like to earn the rep ;)

Comment: I don't answer for reps ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Siddharth Rout found the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14503054/change-the-image-of-an-image-shape#comment20215087_14503054)

I created the image by selecting `picture` from the `insert` menu, but it have to be created via `Insert` => `Rectangular shape` (no border). Now it can easily be accessed by using `ActivePresentation.Slides("Slide1").Shapes("SolutionA_Image").Fill.UserPicture ("D:\User\SolutionWrong.jpg")`