# How to refresh the active Slide in a slide show?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Based on [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14503054/change-the-image-of-an-image-shape) I got the right code to change the image of an shape.
Unfortunatly, this does not update the active Presentation. If I close the presentation and restart it, the image is changed, but the change should be directly visible.

This is my code to change the image:

```
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.Shapes("SolutionA_Image").Fill.UserPicture ("D:\User\SolutionWrong.jpg")
```

I found a way to update the presentation, but this lets the presentation flicker.

```
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.Height = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.Height - 1
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.Height = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.Height + 1
```

**Edit**
I tried refreshing the slide as proposed [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2003-customize/clicking-twice-on-command-button/21792aa0-4bd0-44d2-ae19-5365fe41baeb), but this didn't worked for me.

```
Dim lSlideIndex As Long
lSlideIndex = SlideShowWindows(1).View.CurrentShowPosition
SlideShowWindows(1).View.GotoSlide lSlideIndex
```

**Edit 2**
I uploaded my file: [Download](http://privat.kapistatistik.de/ChangeImage.zip)

Comment: Try changing `SlideShowWindows(1).View.GotoSlide lSlideIndex` to `SlideShowWindows(1).View.GotoSlide lSlideIndex, msoTrue`

Comment: This does not work either

Comment: I just tested the code and it works. how are you running the macro during the slideshow?

Comment: I have a button on my slide which opens an userform. This form contains an other button which starts the function once it is clicked.

Comment: Just recreated the scenario that you mentioned and it works... May I see your file? If yes then upload the file to any free file sharing server and post the link here.

Comment: I'm going to simplify my presentation to this scenario and load it up.

Comment: It works for me :) All I had to do was specify full path in `Fill.UserPicture ("C:\ImageA.jpg")`

Comment: I'm using PowerPoint 2007. Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23324/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-christopher)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I found my answer in [this blog post](http://www.pptalchemy.co.uk/PowerPoint_Screen%20_Refresh.html). It appears to be a bug in PowerPoint 2007.

This code helps to fix the bug:

```
Dim osld As Slide
'get current slide
Set osld = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide
'the next line adds the empty textbox and refreshs the slide
osld.Shapes.AddTextbox msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 1, 1, 1, 1
```

Answer (score 3):

I found this bug in my Power Point as well,
I add this line into the code and it fixes the bug

Application.SlideShowWindows(1).View.GotoSlide Me.SlideIndex

Comment: Thanks for your solution! It worked quite flawlessly for me.

Comment: This works for me as well, but is gives me a bit of a flicker. Is this not the case for you?